A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected YTD
I am trying to calculate a table where I can see the YTD values with this DAX:
Is YTD = 
IF (
    'Append'[Attribute - Date] >= DATE ( YEAR ( DISTINCT ( 'Append'[Date Ref.EoMonth] ) ), 1, 1 )
        && 'Append'[Attribute - Date] <= DISTINCT ( 'Append'[Date Ref.EoMonth] ),
    "YTD",
    "Other"
)

But I get A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

In your case DISTINCT  returns a table of values but DAX expects a single value for comparison in your IF statement.
Try to use MAX or MIN to get a single value  returned from 'Append'[Date Ref.EoMonth] which DAX can use for comparison :
Is YTD = 
IF (
    'Append'[Attribute - Date] >= DATE ( YEAR ( MAX ( 'Append'[Date Ref.EoMonth] ) ), 1, 1 )
        && 'Append'[Attribute - Date] <= MAX ( 'Append'[Date Ref.EoMonth] ),
    "YTD",
    "Other"
)

